# Sharing a repo without git-daemon

Tags: git, shared-hosting

I've asked my shared host company to allow me to have a git repository on their servers.

The answer was:

> Please provide us with a list of the
>   git commands you wish to use. Our
>   system administrators will check them
>   and install them if possible.
>
> However, if you require a GIT-daemon,
>   then this will not be possible, as
>   background processes running on the
>   server are not allowed.

**UPDATE:**

---

> The Git repositories are not supported
>   on our servers, because they require a
>   background process running on the
>   server, which is against our terms of
>   use.
>
> What might be possible is to use git
>   binaries on our server to connect to
>   repositories on third party servers.
>   You would have to provide an exact
>   list of the commands that you are
>   planning to use, so that we could
>   consult with our System
>   administrators.

Can anyone explain this for me?
What commands should I ask them?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 8-Ways to share a git-repository: http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/

Comment: @All: I've update my question because after Benoit answers, the host as replying with more specificity. Can I have your help on the update please?

Answer (score 2):

You can ask for an ssh access, on an account with read/write permissions on git repository folder.

You'll can manage your repository without using git-daemon. Once connected, you only need the "git" command.

If you want a strong authentification system, you can use gitosis or gitolite (both programs use ssh authentification and don't need a deamon process).

Comment: @Benoit Courtine - thanks a lot. So, developer A will need a ssh access, and developer B will need another ssh access as well? I don't need a strong authentication system so I believe. So, I will have my local repository. Developer 2 will have is local repository. We all push to this remote repository, we see if it's ok, then we can pull from that remote repository, all that, by using ssh access and git command? If all the above assumptions are correct: is there any ssh client with some colors to be easy for us, git newbies to work with? (ubuntu environments) :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MEM: You don't have to use the SSH client directly. With a url of the form `user@host/path/to/repo` (or variations thereof), Git will use SSH transparently under the hood when it needs to interact with the remote, e.g. during pushes and pulls. All the user needs is the SSH access itself - preferably using public/private keypair authentication so that you won't need a password every time you pull.

Comment: @Jefromi: thanks a lot for that clarification. So, I only need 1 ssh account access. However, inside that 1 account, a public/private keypar for each developer to interact on that same connection? Is this correct? I'm asking this because my host is replying that they "can't provide multiple SSH log-ins".

Comment: @MEM: You could in fact use different keypairs on the same login - that's exactly how gitolite works. (I'm not sure based on what you're saying if you could get gitolite set up or not - it's essentially a set of perl scripts and some ssh configuration.)

Comment: @Jefromi, can I please ask your help one more time? When my host company says: "What might be possible is to use git binaries on our server to connect to repositories on third party servers. You would have to provide an exact list of the commands that you are planning to use, so that we could consult with our System administrators." If it was you, what will you answer? I'm starting to planning this, without ever done it before, hence, I really have no clues what are the specific commands that they are requiring me to provide. Any help here?

Comment: @MEM: They'll need `git` installed on the server. The only subcommands which will be used are `git shell`, `git receive-pack`, `git upload-pack`, and `git upload-archive`, so conceivably they could just install that subset.

Comment: @Jefromi: You absolutly rock. Now that I'm starting to get how this all things work together, I realise that I can also have my projects on github, and use Capistrano on the dev machines to deploy (by using ssh and sftp) to my shared host, the commited files. Isn't this correct? (I'm thing here, as an alternative, in case they don't allow any of those comments and, as I plus, I really love developing everything opensource, so no issues for me there) what do you thing? Jefromi, you have been a great help in order to realise all this works, I must really thank for that. :)